# How struct size effects automatic marshaling in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, marshalling, unmanaged, managed

I am working on a C# .NET wrapper that wraps an unmanaged C++ Driver. The logic is to create a C# class that has methods which wrap the `DLLImport` entries.

One of the functions of the unmanaged driver expects pointer to a struct. I know that the correct way to pass the struct is by ref because in C# structures are value types [Structure types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct) and since C# is always passing the value it would pass the managed address of the struct while automatically pinning and marshalling (**correct this if I am wrong**)

But for experimentation I didn't passed a `ref` but instead the whole struct and I was expecting to get an exception like memory access denied due to the unmanaged driver would manipulate the parameter as pointer.

I found that this behavior is not the same when the struct is smaller. For example when the struct has only 2 `uint` fields (before had 3 uints) then I get the following exception

`System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'`

Probably due to compiler optimization if the struct size does not exceed some threshold then it manipulates the struct by value and the above exception is thrown, while if the struct exceed the threshold it manipulates is as reference and then **no exception is thrown**.

I didn't find any documentation that states this behavior.

So this got me confused and created some questions. If anyone can answer them it would be very helpful to understand how automatic marshaling is working

1. Why is exception is thrown when struct has 2 uints but not when it has 3 uints?
2. C# doesn't know the unmanaged function prototype right? If so, why when the struct is large and I pass a wrong parameter (e.g. unmanaged function expects pointer but I pass struct or expects struct but I pass reference) the code is working and no exception is thrown.

I will post an example of wrapper/driver projects that I used for testing in case anyone want to try. You can remove the `ref` from the second parameter of `foo` and check the results with different struct sizes.

---

C++ Driver

Datatypes.h

```
#pragma once

#include"basetsd.h"

typedef struct _TestStruct
{
    UINT32 x;
    UINT32 y;
    UINT32 z;

} TestStruct;
```

main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include"main.h"
#include"basetsd.h"
#include"Datatypes.h"

using namespace std;

int foo(TestStruct p, TestStruct *p2)
{
    p2->x = 10;
    p.x = 11;

    cout << "p address  0x" << &p << endl;
    cout << "p2 value   0x" << &(*p2) << endl;
    cout << "p2 address 0x" << &p2 << endl;

    while (1);

    return 0;
}
```

main.h

```
#pragma once

#include"Datatypes.h"

#ifdef _EXPORTING
#define DECLSPEC __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DECLSPEC __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {  // only need to export C interface if
    // used by C++ source code
#endif

DECLSPEC int foo(TestStruct p, TestStruct *p2);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

---

C# Wrapper

wrapper.cs

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Wrapper
{
    public struct WTestStruct
    {
        public uint x;
        public uint y;
        public uint z;
        public uint c;
    }

    internal class wrapper
    {
        [DllImport("Driver.dll", EntryPoint = "foo", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern int Foo(WTestStruct p, ref WTestStruct p2);
    }
}
```

main.cs

```
using System;

namespace Wrapper
{
    class main
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            WTestStruct p = new WTestStruct();
            p.x = 1;
            p.y = 2;
            p.z = 3;
            p.c = 4;

            wrapper.Foo(p, ref p);

            Console.WriteLine("x: {0}", p.x);

            Console.WriteLine("Executed");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It has to do with alignment.  When c# calls a c++ routine there is memory protection that is added so when access outside the memory segment occurs an exception will occur.  So normally the memory segment is on 64 bit memory (long).  So when you have two int32 you do not exceed the memory limits, but three int32 will give exception.  So in c# you must allocate the right amount of memory so you do not exceed the memory limits.  A intptr in c# has a size and that size specifies the memory in c++ exception so you get an exception is c++ tries to access memory outside the limits.

Comment: Bad declarations may seem to work by accident.  The accident here is caused by the convention used to pass "large" structs by value.  The caller then allocates space for the struct and copies the value into it.  And passes a pointer to that copy, making the distinction disappear.  Well, other than that the C++ code is now directly accessing the stack frame of the C# code, that can cause plenty of hilarity when it writes.  No AVE to tell you about it.  The exact rules for "large" are not well documented btw, Windows and Unix don't use the same rules, more than 64 bits for x64 code afaik.

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks for the response, it helped a lot.

Of course as @Hans Passant said

> Bad declarations may seem to work by accident

So this is definitely not an issue on the marshaling or on .NET part, but it is an issue on the developer side. Beside this is well documented in .NET

> The Rect value type must be passed by reference because the unmanaged API is expecting a pointer to a RECT to be passed to the function - [Default marshalling for value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshalling-behavior#default-marshalling-for-value-types)

But lets continue with the investigation.

---

> The caller then allocates space for the struct and copies the value into it. And passes a pointer to that copy, making the distinction disappear.

So if I understand correctly when the struct is "large" the managed code will pass the address even if the parameter is not defined with 'ref'. But I think this would only work if the following is correct.

Since P/Invoke doesn't know if the unmanaged function expects pointer or struct it will place the struct on the stack and the address will be passed with the registers (and not with the stack to not mess with the alignment). Therefore if the unmanaged function wants the value then it will look at the stack else if it wants the pointer it will look at the registers.

After some testing I found out using the posted wrapper and driver that indeed the RCX register contains an address on stack and that address when looking at the Memory window on Visual Studio has the values 1, 2, 3 and 4 with 4 bytes each so I assume this is the struct.

Thanks again for the help